# Почему файл пишется как папка?

Tags: java, файлы

Существует директория /home/danpetruk.

Запускаю:

```
File fil = new File("/home/danpetruk/translates/values/strings.xml");
fil.mkdirs();
fil.createNewFile();
```

Получаю:

1. Папку translates
2. Внутри папку values
3. Внутри папку(!) strings.xml

Вопрос: как его заставить создавать strings.xml как файл, а не как паку?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
File fil = new File("/home/danpetruk/translates/values/strings.xml");
fil.getParentFile().mkdirs();
fil.createNewFile();
```